# how to render partial view in popup box in asp.net mvc 4 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-5

On clicking on textbox, I need to display popup box with two options as Present and Absent menu in popup box,
On selecting either of those options. I need to render partial view of present status or Absent status views.
And finally save status in textbox I clicked initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind click on your textbox on ajax call to get partial view from server. Next actions must do on client side, I think.

At first you must have Action like this:

```
[HttpGet]    
public ActionResult PresentStatus()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

On client side you can write something like this:

```
<script>
    $.get('/controllerName/presentstatus/', function(data){
        showPopup(data);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for reply. If possible plz provide code how to render partial view using ajax/jquery. @Maskim

Comment: That is fine thank you, but how to render partial view in popup. Script you is to be placed where ? and what is use? plz clarify me